# Speed-up application by remove code for writing logs?

Tags: java, android, logging, google-glass

I am trying to speed-up my application. 
Will it make my app significantly faster if I remove all the logs-code? Does it make a difference ?

My app writes lots of logs.

```
Log.v(TAG, "example android log");
```

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316495/how-to-make-my-code-fast), but it doesnt answer my question.

Comment: Stop writing logs  will help to improve the performance, but that you need work your code first . Writing logs take time only when you are writing too many logs . Otherwise work on functional code , which part taking time.  Better post details of application .

Comment: Use optimized code. Check major functionalities of app, if code can be optimized and iterations can be minimized.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't make any visible improvements on your perfs.

Unless you're doing really bad things such as:

- Non-stop logging (100x every frame)
- String concatenations
- `toString()` method calls
- any object allocation

Maybe you could share some snippets of your logging code to see if there is anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the functionalities of you Glass app. If your glass app is just a slideshow there are different aspects that needs to be taken care of than a Media Streaming app. Offcourse, reducing the number of log statements would help a bit in the performance but there are other significant points that should be taken into consideration.

Please refer to this [official Google Document](https://developers.google.com/glass/performance)  for more detail information.